# Qt QAudioOutput buffer underflow when playing from file

Tags: qt, audio, file-io, buffer, underflow

I have implemented a simple Qt program based on the example in the `QAudioOutput` documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiooutput.html).

The program plays raw audio from a file using `QAudioOutput` when I press a button.

The audio plays fine but I receive `Got a buffer underflow!` at the end of the file before `QAudioOutput` changes to the idle state.

Is this a normal indication that `QAudioOutput` has reached the end of the file, and I should ignored it, or is this an indication that `QAudio` has overshot the end of the file, and that I should address it somehow?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: You can access the code here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ddlz2z4nibxw1a6/AACqjQs4q2VPMUvdH1Gy5cWTa?dl=0

Comment: Please post your code in your question. Link may get broken in future and your question will become irrelevant for others having similar questions.